# Is it possible to find the current used hours on the Free Plan via the Heroku API?

Tags: heroku

I know that Heroku will send an email when 80% of a month's free hours have been consumed, and another at 100%. I'd like to be able to use the Heroku API to trigger additional alerts, e.g., at 50% usage.

I've reviewed the API documentation and this is possible for teams but free dynos aren't available for teams. That is, checking `weighted_dyno_hours` which is "[t]he total amount of hours consumed across dyno types" is available on the [team invoice](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#team-invoice) but seems not to be deployed for free dynos.

It's that's just the state of things, due perhaps to minimizing the costs of supporting free features, that's completely rational. I just want to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that via the API, but you can [via the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#determining-your-free-dyno-hours):

> You can view the amount of free dyno hours remaining by using the CLI. You can do this by running `heroku ps` on one of your free apps.
>
> ```
> heroku ps -a <app name>
>
> 650 free dyno hours (65%) used
> 350 hours remaining
>
> === web (Free): bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb (1)
> web.1: idle 2016/05/16 15:51:45 -0700 (~ 22h ago)
> ```

If you really want to check this automatically you could schedule this to run and parse the output, though I'm not sure that I'd recommend that.

This information is also visible in the web dashboard (see the same previous link).

Heroku's [help center doesn't suggest anything else](https://help.heroku.com/FRHZA2YG/how-do-i-monitor-my-free-dyno-hours-quota).